# Intuition behind convergence of MCMC inference methods

Tags: statistical-inference, machine-learning, sampling, monte-carlo

I'm studying Gibbs Sampling for inference, a popular MCMC algorithm and I was stunned by its ability to fit a Gaussian Mixture just by sampling.

I would like to know the intuition behind it, and why it works.